# I cannot overide a style from materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to apply the style to the .lvl-2 to apply an indent to a particular div, but it is getting overriden by something in materialize.

Chrome inspector scrennshots below

[image: the style that overrides]

[image: My style in inspector]

I have some HTML (below is excerpt it is in a list)

```
       <li key={elements.index}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col red s4">f</div>
            <div className="col blue s8">f</div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col red s4 lvl-2">indented</div>
            <div className="col green s8">f</div>
          </div>
```

I have some CSS

```
li> .lvl-2 {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

I have also tried being more specific but when I do inspector doesn't see the style at all (which is wierd )

```
li div> div .lvl-2 {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

The problem is that when I view in the inspector it say that the style is being overwritten by the style below from materialize

```
ul:not(.browser-default) {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Unfortunately if I just override it it won't work because I want different syles on different li's

```
ul:not(.browser-default) {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS was incorrect defined, that's the reason why you don't see your style applied.

With your HTML markup:

```html
<li key={elements.index}>
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col red s4">f</div>
    <div className="col blue s8">f</div>
  </div>
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col red s4 lvl-2">indented</div>
    <div className="col green s8">f</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

And you want to style `.lvl-2`, the proper one should be : `li .row .lvl-2 {}` ,

Of course the CSS specificity might not be stronger than the one defined in Material UI, in that case you should add more specificity, something like:
`ul li > .row > .col.lvl-2`

Please, never ever using "!important" unless you're forced to. In this scenario, it's still quite easy to fix and this will save your future-self.

=========
Updated answer on Nov 18th:

Let's go through each of your attempt one by one and see what went wrong:

1)

```
li> .lvl-2 {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

This means "get all **the direct child elements** with `.lvl-2` class from `li`", this won't apply because your HTML markup is different.

To be more specific, your `lvl-2` element has a wrapper div with class `row`, as of now the direct children from `li` are divs with `.row` class. The `>` stands for "get direct child`.

If you want to use direct selector, the selector should be like `li .row > .lvl-2`.

2)

```
li div> div .lvl-2 {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

Once again, the CSS won't run because your HTML markup is different from what your CSS defines.

In this case, it means "from any `li` element, select all `divs` children, from each selected `div`, get all direct `div` children, then get all element with `.lvl-2` class from each direct selected `div`.".

That might be hard to get the first time, but let me show you the HTML markup which will work in your second attempt.

```
<li>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="lvl-2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

or even another markup

```
li
  div
    div
      div
        div.lvl-2
```

To answer for your question, I think you should read on this article, it will help you easier than my explanation "https://dev.to/emmawedekind/css-specificity-1kca"

In your scenario, and also from my experience, you should define CSS selectors using class, not with type selectors (e.g like `div, li, button`).

- Type selector is the lowest priority in CSS specificity calculation. Use with caution.
- In term of project scalability, using type selector means you're forcing the element to be that specific type. E.g: `li span` means only the `<span>` tag, what happens if another developer or an upcoming request change, that tag needs to be replaced with a `div`. So saving your future-self, use with classes like `li .item`, it will both apply either to `<li> <span class="item">` or `<li> <div class="item">`.
- It reduces confusion as much as possible, and increase readability CSS code. Reading something `.list .item` always helps a clearer vision than a `li span`.
- Most of the time, when your Frontend architect depends on a 3rd party like Bootstrap or Material-UI, they all use class selectors. To override them, the only way is to use class selectors.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Duc - that works but I don't understand why I can't use the elements instead of the classes EG why isn't      li  div .lvl-2 interchangeable with li .row .lvl-2

Comment: @Paul A please see the updated answer for your question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `!important` which is an exception to the [specificity calculation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rule.

```
li > .lvl-2 {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px !important;
}
```

MDN excerpt:

> **The !important exception**
>
> When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declarations. Although technically
>   `!important` has nothing to do with specificity, it interacts directly
>   with it. Using `!important`, however, is **bad practice** and should be
>   avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the
>   natural cascading in your stylesheets. When two conflicting
>   declarations with the `!important` rule are applied to the same element,
>   the declaration with a greater specificity will be applied.
>
> **Some rules of thumb:**
>
> - **Always** look for a way to use specificity before even considering
>     `!important`
> - **Only** use `!important` on page-specific CSS that overrides
>     foreign CSS (from external libraries, like Bootstrap or
>     normalize.css).
> - **Never** use `!important` when you're writing a
>     plugin/mashup.
> - **Never** use `!important` on site-wide CSS.

Comment: In this scenario, it's still be better to apply a more specific CSS selector rather than using `!important` flag

Comment: @DucHong: using specific css selector is *always* better. using `!important` is bad practice. This is all mentioned in the post if you read

Comment: what I meant was, why would you recommend a bad practice to resolve a solution that can be fixed in a proper way? Showing him just "use !important"  might make him blindly follow and believe that's the magic. Sorry but I had to deal with these kind of FE devs who just copy and paste a solution from SO without understanding the root cause. So, seeing your kind of answer is really a red flag to me.

Answer (score 2):

try be more specific like:

```
ul:not(.browser-default) li .lvl-2 {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

avoid using `!important` if you can, this will bring pain later

also i think the culprit is not the padding on `ul:not(.browser-default)` since this should apply to the `ul` element, not to it's children

Answer (score 1):

use **!important** keyword

Example : width :100px  into width :100px !important

Answer (score 0):

Use `.browser-default` class to revert overriding the default browser styling:

```
<ul className='browser-dafault'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```